# Firefox extensions: are cross-domain JSON calls allowed?

Tags: json, firefox

Can a Firefox extension/add-on make a cross-domain JSON request? Normally for in-page javascript this is not allowed, forcing a JSONP work-around.

Thanks Richard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  A Firefox add-on can do pretty much anything.